# Why text on SWC won't show up when imported from FlashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript, embed, flashdevelop, swc

I've posted this question before but no useful answer was found. People told me to use embedAsCFF=false, but I'm not embedding any font directly.

There is a textfield using "Impact" as font inside a movieclip. I exported the movieclip as an swc so that I would be able to use it's graphics in my Flashdevelop project.
When I add the swc to the screen, everything is fine but the text. It doesn't appear.

```
var swcInstance:SwcClass = new SwcClass
swcInstance.textFiel.text = "hello world!"
addChild(swcInstance)
```

Hope I explained it well

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a "Classic TextField" and not a "TLF TextField" in Flash Pro.

Also make sure you embed the needed character for the font - see Properties panel for your field instance in Flash Pro and check at least Basic Latin (and Latin 1 for accented characters).